# How can I remove/disable edit button from Address Information Block from Admin sales order detail page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

As per specific order status I want to restrict user to make changes in order address i.e

I want to disable or remove the edit button from Billing & Shipping Address from Address Information block

Please check the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BoFC.png

Comment: show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the links are coming from below template file:

[Magento Root]/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Please check below screenshot of the file:
[image]

To remove the links in your module then you can rewrite the layout file: 
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/**sales_order_view.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml">
    <container name="extra_customer_info"/>
</block>
```

In your module, in sales_order_view.xml layout file add your template file path:

```
<referenceBlock name="order_info">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```